# Freezing at login on Dell XPS 15 9560 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login, dell, xps

I fresh installed Ubuntu 18.04 (no dual boot) on my Dell XPS 15 9560. When I enter my password the login screen UI disappears, and the background and my mouse freeze. How to prevent Ubuntu 18.04 from freezing at the login screen?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Dell XPS 15 9560 has an Nvidia GTX 1050 GPU with 4GB RAM dedicated memory, but maybe the GTX 1050 doesn't have a proprietary driver installed for it. If you can't login to the desktop environment to install the proprietary Nvidia graphics driver, you can access a virtual console and install the graphics driver from there.

From the login screen before entering your password logging press the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to access a text-only virtual console.

To login from a virtual console:

1. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
2. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. After you have logged in, you can run commands from the virtual console.

The proprietary Nvidia graphics driver can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 from the terminal/console with the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
sudo reboot
```

When installing a proprietary graphics driver, it is not necessary to uninstall the built-in open source graphics driver. The two graphics drivers can be installed alongside each other allowing the  open source graphics driver to be used as a fallback alternative in case there is a problem using the proprietary graphics driver.

The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the Nvidia driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available.

Comment: Perfect ! Thenk you very much !

Comment: Brilliant! I had the same problem and this fixed it. Thank you.