# Not able to install graphic card drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am trying to install graphic card drivers for my GTX 1060

first I ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`  for recommended driver

[image]

which is **415** version

But as you can see in screenshot that apply button is disabled for only 415 option

[image]

how can I install that?

Comment: What driver is shown in use if you type in `nvidia-smi` from a terminal window?

Comment: The proprietary graphics driver for the Nvidia GTX 1060 can also be installed directly from the default Ubuntu repositories instead of installing it from a PPA, if you uninstall the existing Nvidia proprietary graphics driver, disable the PPA, and run `sudo apt update && sudo reboot` first. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091263/freezing-at-login-on-dell-xps-15-9560-with-ubuntu-18-04/1091574#1091574).

Answer (score 0):

Before everything, run `nvidia-smi` to see which driver version do you have. If you have a version lower than the recommended one, then try this method (it worked for me with Nvidia GeForce 940MX):

1. Run this command `ubuntu-drivers devices` to see which Nvidia
   driver is recommended for your graphic card
2. Run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`.

If the previous command didn't install the desired version of Nvidia drivers, try this: `sudo apt install nvidia-<driver_version>`.

You can find more information and different methods [in this link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)